# How do i show the data of a table in the (View) of another form in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am beginner with RoR and `active admin`. I have two models `consumer` and `customer ledger`. `consumer` model is linked with `customer` model using `Single Table Inheritance`  I have to show all the customer ledger entries of a consumer, on the View page of that consumer.

code of `customer` model:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    serialize(:delivery_days, Array)
    has_one :customer_ledger
    has_many :sales_orders
    has_many :production_requests
    has_many :locations
    has_many :product_rates
    has_many :service_rates
    belongs_to :customer_ledger
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_rates, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_rates, allow_destroy: true

    validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, :allow_blank => true
    validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :mobile_no, presence: true,:numericality => true, :length => { :minimum => 11, :maximum => 15 }
    validates :landline, :numericality => true,:length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 15 }, :allow_blank => true
    validates :mode_of_payment, presence: true
    validates_associated :locations
    validates :locations, presence: true
    scope :consumers, -> { where(type: 'Consumer') }
    scope :businesses, -> { where(type: 'Business') }
end
```

code of `consumer` model:

```
class Consumer < Customer
    validates :paid_security_amount, presence: true
    validates_associated :product_rates
    validates :product_rates, presence: true

end
```

code of `customer ledger` model:

```
class CustomerLedger < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :sales_orders
    has_many :production_requests
end
```

How can i show all the `Customer Ledger` information in the `show` of `activeadmin` form?

Comment: Have you activeadmin already installed inside your project?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://activeadmin.info/6-show-pages.html

Comment: @Prometheus, Yes.. I have installed it.

Comment: @ZulqarnainAbbas have you added any model to activeadmin?